# How to do file not found show waring?

Tags: python

If no input file will show Error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` But I want to show a warning to remind users to input files outside, how to do?

```
def get_xml_name():
    args = sys.argv
    if len(args) > 1 :
       args = args[1]
       strA = "".join(args)
       return strA



inputfile = open(get_xml_name() , 'r')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: `with open(get_xml_name() , 'r') as f:`

Comment: `with` means that you want to do _something_ with the file in the next line. Change it to `open(get_xml_name() , 'r')` or better use `.exists()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
with open(get_xml_name() , 'r') as f:
```

use

```
f = open(get_xml_name() , 'r')
```

then later

```
f.close()
```